Kafka spring integration failure not passing to failure channel
When any failure happen in Kafka  flow i cant see failure  going to failure channel (Sucess flow works fine). Below is my config
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaCommonOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                        kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                        header-mapper="kafkaHeaderMapper"
                                        send-failure-channel="failureChannel"
                                        send-success-channel="successChannel"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        topic-expression="headers['topic']"
                                        partition-id-expression="headers['partition']"
                                        sync="true">
 <int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>

And failure channel is
    <int:chain input-channel="failureChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="someBean" method="handleFailure"/>
</int:chain>

If i change this to use int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain then it work fine. Below is config
       <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaCommonOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                        kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                        header-mapper="kafkaHeaderMapper"                                        
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        topic-expression="headers['topic']"
                                        partition-id-expression="headers['partition']"
                                        sync="true">
        <int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="requestHandlerAdvice"/>-->
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
</int:chain>


<bean id="requestHandlerAdvice"
      class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="trapException" value="true"/>
    <property name="onSuccessExpression" ref="success"/>
    <property name="successChannelName" value="successChannel"/>
    <property name="onFailureExpression" ref="failure"/>
    <property name="failureChannelName" value="failureChannel"/>
</bean>

Only thing i changed to use
send-failure-channel="failureChannel" send-success-channel="successChannel"  instead request handler advise chain.

Any chances you can share with us a simple project to reproduce? According to the code in the KafkaProducerMessageHandler, it supposes to work even with that sync="true" mode.
